# Kaminari page_method_name configuration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, kaminari

I have a Rails 4.2 framework and use Kaminari to paginate. Everything works great, but I want to test everything with Capybara, thus I run into the page conflict. So I wanted to rename the page_method_name of Kaminari and followed the guide from them:

```
$ bundle exec rails g Kaminari:config
```

This results in this file

**app/config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb**

```rb
Kaminari.configure do |config|
     config.page_method_name = :plant
end
```

In which I simply uncommented the config.page_method_name and set it to :plant (as an example from the Kaminari docs to avoid any reserved method name conflicts for something like :kaminari_page).
Then I adjusted the appropriate controller to

```rb
    def index
      @q = Interaction.published.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(200).ransack(params[:q])
      @selection = @q.result
      @interactions = Kaminari.paginate_array(@selection).plant(params[:page]).per(10)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end
```

I restarted everything and got this error when visiting the

**undefined method `plant' for #Kaminari::PaginatableArray:0x00005568fb42ba30**

**Gemfile.lock:**

```
kaminari (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)
    kaminari-core (1.2.1)
```

I was then googling around and also added require 'kaminari' (which does not make so much sense, because I did not get the uninit constant error) and also included the Kaminari configure section into the class Application < Rails::Application inside config/application.rb.
Nothing worked, always the same error.

Comment: Does @selection contain a plant method?

Comment: No, I edited my question appropriately providing a full overview of the index action.

Answer (score 0):

You show your files location as `app/config/initializiers/kaminari_config.rb`. If that is the actual location of your file it fully explains why the method doesn't exist.  The location should be `app/config/initializers/kaminari_config.rb`. With the location you specified it wouldn't be automatically loaded when the app starts.

If the location you showed is just a type then that wouldn't be the cause, but if you didn't include Capybara into the global object, which you shouldn't be doing anyway, then you wouldn't have a name collision.  Current versions of Capybara issue a warning when you do include it into the global object specifically for this reason.

Also is there any reason you're grabbing all the results and then paging them, rather than using the `page` (or `plant`) and `per` scopes that would be defined on Interaction?

Comment: Thank you Thomas Walpole for your answer! and sorry for that typo! Sure the location is in initializers without an additional i. 
I did not include Capybara into the global object and I do not get an error, but I cannot use capybara on any of the paginated tables. So I thought it is just the page issue. Still the reconfig of Kaminari should work, shouldn't it? For you last point, can you give me an example where you would place the `page` and `per` for the model Interaction?

Comment: @StephanSinn I believe `Interaction.published.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(200).ransack(params[:q]).page(params[:page]).per(19)` should work.  Yes the renaming should work if you're using a new enough version of kaminari -- The fact that you're using Rails 4.2 tells me you may be out of date on all of these gems

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that. You have another idea about the failed reconfig of the page method?

Comment: @StephanSinn do you happen to be using kaminari <= 0.15?

Comment: no it is v1.2.1, I updated my post including the Gemfile.lock excerpt.

Comment: I tested your ransack, kaminari combination. That does not work. page is not existing for a Ransack:Search and adding .result will raise the error that ransack needs a Ransack:Search (@q) for sorting. Anyways thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @StephanSinn try just calling .page(..).per on result rather than wrapping result in  paginate_array. Been a while since I’ve used ransack but one of those should work. It’s definitely possible to only load the needed records for the current page from the DB

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the scope hints, I will check on that and play. Any idea for the main topic of the question being the config of kaminari?